# Ruby conversion gem errors with production on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, units-of-measurement

I've tried using both the ruby units https://github.com/olbrich/ruby-units and alchemist https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist gems in my app for conversions. Everything works perfect locally, even in production mode.

On my Linode, however, the conversions are raising exceptions, even though the alchemist gem works perfectly in the production rails console.

Is there an extra require step or configuration necessary to use these ruby gems within my rails app? Do I need to call `require 'alchemist'` in an initializer? How do pure ruby gems fit into Rails, and how are they configured?

Here is the line in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'alchemist'
```

Here's the production console output (which works):

```
deployer@li60-239:~/apps/saute/current$ bundle exec rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> Alchemist
=> Alchemist
irb(main):002:0> 1.tablespoon
=> 1.0
irb(main):003:0> 1.tablespoon.class
=> Alchemist::NumericConversion
```

But within my app, I get an exception in my logs:

```
Exception in base quantity method: undefined method `tablespoon' for #<BigDecimal:beb7548,'0.1E1',4(8)>
Quantity: 1.0
```

UPDATE:

I created `config/initializers/alchemist.rb`:

```
require 'alchemist'
```

This didn't cause any problems locally in development. Everything still worked. But then I get the folling error in production:

/home/deployer/apps/saute/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-     3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- alchemist (LoadError)

How do I configure this!

Comment: Did you run bundle install on your production server?

Comment: Yes. I'm using capistrano which automatically bundles, but I just did it again. Same problem.

Comment: When you deploy, the rails server (unicorn, passenger, etc) restarts correctly?

Comment: Unicorn restarts perfectly. So does nginx. I can view a few pages of my app without a hitch, but on this specific page I get the error. I definitely think its a ruby load path kind of problem...